# How to link to a single edit page in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am working on a basic AngularJs application to manage a clients list. I currently have a view where I can add and delete clients. I'm would like to create a view where I can edit data.

I'm trying to **create the right route to this "single item" view.** Here is what I got up to now:

**HTML** (where I want to put the link)

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr><th>Prénom</th><th>Nom</th><th>Modifier</th><th>Supprimer</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="client in clients">
      <td><a href="{{client.$id}}">{{client.prenom}}</a></td>
      <td>{{client.nom}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module("crmfirebase", [
    "ngCookies",
    "ngResource",
    "ngSanitize",
    "ngRoute",
    "firebase"
    ]);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'accueil.html'
      }).
      when('/clients', {
        templateUrl: 'clients.html',
        controller: 'ClientsCtrl'
      }).
      when('/clients/:clientId', {
        templateUrl: 'client.html',
        controller: 'ClientsCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);

app.value('fbURL', 'https://mydatabaseurl.firebaseio.com/clients');

app.controller('ClientsCtrl', function ($scope, fbURL, $firebase) {

  var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabaseurl.firebaseio.com/clients");
  $scope.clients = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

  $scope.removeClient = function(client) {
    $scope.clients.$remove(client);
  };

  $scope.addClient = function (client) {
    $scope.clients.$add(client);
  };

  $scope.updateClient = function (client) {
    $scope.clients.$save(client);
  };

}); //End Controller
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really ask a question. But since your code is missing the part where you assign the object to the detail/client view, I'll focus on that.

In your ClientCtrl you'll simply set up a new reference and sync point for the current client. So something like:

```
app.controller('ClientCtrl', function($scope, FBURL, $firebase, $routeParams) {
    $scope.boardId = board.id;
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL+"clients/"+$routeParams.clientId);

    var client= $firebase(ref).$asObject();
    client.$bindTo($scope, 'client');
});
```

Then you can simply bind to the properties in your client.html:

```
<h2><a href='#/board/{{client.$id}}'>{{client.name}}</a></h2>
<article ng-controller='ClientCtrl' ng-model='client'>
    <label>Name: </label><input ng-model='client.name' autofocus></input>
    <label>Age: </label><input ng-model='client.age'></input>
    <button ng-click='removeClient(client.$id)'>Delete</button>
</article>
```

And you link to your detail view from clients.html with:

```
 <td><a href="#/client/{{client.$id}}">{{client.prenom}}</a></td>
```

All code copied and modified from my pet project here: https://github.com/puf/trenches.

Comment: What could be the solution if I want to use "asArray" instead of "asObject" ?

Comment: I haven't tried. But why not simply do as I did? I use **both** `asArray` and `asObject`, Firebase handles the data transfer behind the scenes.

Comment: @LucienDubois debug the error and compare your code to Frank's, look in the docs and pinpoint the problem. If you haven't resolved it by then, ask another question here and we'll help out. But it starts with you doing the leg work; we can't really intuit your code or errors from a comment thread.